# Why is line from file not printed in java

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to read a file in java. In that file, some string is given which I want to print. But my code prints only lines of even numbers and skips lines of odd numbers.

I searched for that in stackoverflow, but have found no solution previously answered.

My code is given below...

```
//main class
import java.io.IOException;


public class takingInputFrpmFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String filePath = "F:/Path/in.txt";

        try 
        {
            readFile rF = new readFile(filePath);
            String[] receivedArray = rF.Read();

            for(int i=0;i<receivedArray.length;i++)
                System.out.println(receivedArray[i]);

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

// class called from main class

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class readFile {

    private String path;

    public readFile(String path)
    {
        this.path=path;
    }

    public String[] Read() throws IOException 
    {
        FileReader fR = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(fR);

        String[] textData = new String[110];
        String check;
        int i=0;

        while((check = bR.readLine()) != null)
        {
            textData[i] = bR.readLine();
            i++;
        }

        bR.close();
        return textData;
    }
}
```

The file contains this lines...

[image]

This is the output of my code....

[image]

What is wrong with my code? What should I change? How to get rid of printing that last nulls ? Help please... Thanks in advance...

Comment: So, you create an array with 110 elements, without knowing how many lines there will be? Try it with a list, and add the elements there.
Following naming conventions makes your code easier to read, btw.

Comment: Because you call `bR.readLine();` twice. Should be `textData[i] = check`

Comment: I tried with this ... if(receivedArray[i]==null) break; But don't know, if it is the best solution... :( Is there no way using array ?  @Stultuske

Comment: Mukit: unless you know up forehand the number of elements, you should not use an array. but your problem is indeed what Albert, Antonio and the others suggest.
The point is not what you read, rather how you handle the lines that are read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading file lines twice, one when you do

```
check = bR.readLine()
```

and other when you do

```
textData[i] = bR.readLine();
```

(Each bR.readLine() reads one line)
Try changing your loop for something like

```
while ((textData[i] = bR.readLine()) != null) {
    i++;
}
```

To get rid of the nulls, you can use a List instead of using a fixed size (110) array.

I suggest the following code:

```
//main class
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String filePath = "E:/Temp/in.txt";

        try {
            ReadFile rF = new ReadFile(filePath);
            List<String> receivedArray = rF.read();

            for (String currentLine : receivedArray) {
                System.out.println(currentLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

//class called from main class

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadFile {

    private final String path;

    public ReadFile(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public List<String> read() throws IOException {
        // Create an empty List to protect against NPE
        List<String> textData = new ArrayList<String>();

        FileReader fR = null;
        BufferedReader bR = null;

        try {
            fR = new FileReader(path);
            bR = new BufferedReader(fR);

            String line;

            while ((line = bR.readLine()) != null) {
                textData.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            // Close all the open resources
            bR.close();
            fR.close();
        }

        return textData;
    }
}
```

Anyway, as Mukit Chowdhury suggested, please respect code conventions to make your code more readable (you can Google "Java code conventions" or use a [well stablished ones](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html))

Answer (score 5):

You are first reading the line and checking it's not null, then you read another line.

```
while((check = bR.readLine()) != null)
{
    textData[i] = check; //Changed this to check
    i++;
}
```

That one will work.

You are currently declaring String array which has size of 110. Is your file really 110 line long? You probably should use list instead.

```
public List<String> Read() throws IOException 
{
    FileReader fR = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(fR);

    List<String> textData = new ArrayList<>();
    String check;

    while((check = bR.readLine()) != null)
    {
        textData.add(check);
    }

    bR.close();
    return textData;
}
```

If you really want to return string array you can use:

```
return textData.toArray(new String[textData.size()]);
```

Comment: How to get rid of that nulls ? I tried with this ... if(receivedArray[i]==null)
     break; But don't know, if it is the best solution... :(

Comment: What do you mean? You already check that you are not placing any nulls inside your array in that loop.

Comment: I'm printing that lines from that file. After printing that lines some null values are also printed. When printing through loop in main class, I added that condition.
But I want to know, is there any other way so that the array received in the main class will only contain elements of the file? No null values will be there.

Comment: Check my answer, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you do 2 read statements. Try something like:

```
while((check = bR.readLine()) != null)
{
    textData[i] = check;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your line pointer incrementing two times,

```
while((check = bR.readLine()) != null){
    textData[i] = bR.readLine();
   i++;
}
```

Replace `bR.readLine()` to `check` in your while loop.

```
while((check = bR.readLine()) != null){
        textData[i] = check ;
       i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `readline` twice. Your loop should read

```
for(; (check = br.readline()) != null; textdata[i++] = check);
```

Or something to that effect

Answer (score 1):

From your code sample
here

```
while((check = bR.readLine()) != null) {
    textData[i] = bR.readLine();
    i++;
}
```

replace it with

```
while((check = bR.readLine()) != null) {
    textData[i] = check ;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, reading all lines from a File into a `List<String>` is easily done using utility classes from the `java.nio.file` package:

```
try {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/file"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle error
}
```

It's really no longer necessary to use external libraries or to re-invent the wheel for such a common task :)